# apriori/ aposteriori estimates for partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

There is [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_priori_estimate) explanation on apriori estimate. However, it is still not clear enough. Is there any easy explanations to a non-pde-expert for the difference between apriori and aposteriori estimate in PDE theory? For instance, using some illustrative example will be beneficial.

Comment: Read the wiki article on Kalman filtering. It may help your understanding of apriori and aposteriori.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are trying to ask but here is my answer.

As it said in the wiki link you provided. "apriori" estimation means that: "**IF** we have a solution for a PDE, then this solution should have those properties." In another word, we don't know whether we can have a solution or not, but if we do, the solution should have certain properties.

Here is an example.

Suppose we have elliptic operator 
$$ Lu:=-a_{ij}\partial_i\partial_j u+b_i\partial u+cu $$
where $c\geq 0$, and a PDE question 
\begin{cases}
Lu=0&x\in \Omega\\
u=0&x\in \partial\Omega
\end{cases}

We have no idea whether there exists a solution $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C^0(\bar\Omega)$ or not. But we could make apriori estimation to observe that **IF** there is a solution, then the solution must be $0$.